# In SQL, how do I convert a date field into a string if null?

Tags: sql, date, select, sql-server-2008-r2, case

I would like to write an SQL query in SQL Server 2008 R2 that converts a date to a string when it is NULL. For example...

```
    Date                            ShipmentRef     RecieptNo
    2009-01-01 03:12:11.596         DS298-YYY       18060
                                    FM298-YYY       95464
    2010-11-11 08:33:55.974         IL298-YYY       56703
    2003-08-01 07:00:44.846         UI835-XYX       40264
                                    US655-YXY       34643
    2004-03-07 12:46:33.352         WE242-XXX       83755
```

The above data is just a sample table of what my current data looks like. When I run the SELECT query, I want it to return the data as follows:

```
    Date                            ShipmentRef     RecieptNo
    2009-01-01 03:12:11.596         DS298-YYY       18060
    InsertRandomStringHere          FM298-YYY       95464
    2010-11-11 08:33:55.974         IL298-YYY       56703
    2003-08-01 07:00:44.846         UI835-XYX       40264
    InsertRandomStringHere          US655-YXY       34643
    2004-03-07 12:46:33.352         WE242-XXX       83755
```

I'm not sure which would be better, CASE or CONVERT. Any help you give me will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? MS SQL, MySQL, Oracle, DB2, whatever?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 - My post has now been edited to reflect this. Sorry!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming SQL-Server:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(nVarChar(30), Date, 121), 'InsertRandomStringHere')
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7324)

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Yes, SQL Server 2008. Sorry - I'll edit my message specifying that. Which part of that query targets the specific field?

Comment: @Natalie: The field is named `Date`, isn't it? Of course you need to add the `From` clause if you want to select from a table.

Comment: Ah yes - Sorry! I should've put something like "DeliveryDate" to avoid confusion. That worked! Thank you!!

Comment: @TimSchmelter Would it be possible to replace 'InsertRandomStringHere' with a horizontal tab character?

Comment: Yes. that's possible. Use the [**ACSII table**](http://awesomesql.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/ascii-character-set-table/) for `CHAR`. `Char(9)` is the horizontal tab: `select 'InsertRandom' + char(9) + 'StringHere'`

Answer (score 4):

```
COALESCE(datefield, 'InsertRandomStringHere')
```

(though as others point out, for some DBMS you may need to do additional typecasting operations).

Comment: Since `datetime` has a higher precedence than `varchar`, this should give a conversion error. F.e. `select coalesce(cast(null as datetime), 'hi')` -> `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Answer (score 1):

It depends what exactly you want to achieve.

Each value in column has to be the same type (in MS-SQL at least), so all values in `Date` columns have to be `VARCHAR` type if you want ''random string'' in case of `NULL` date.

Then something like:

```
SELECT CAST(COALESCE(GETDATE(), 'InsertRandomStringHere') AS VARCHAR) AS DATE
UNION
SELECT CAST(COALESCE(NULL, 'InsertRandomStringHere') AS VARCHAR)
```

should work.

However it could make hard to read values from `Date` column in your app (if there is an app) on the other end of wire.

Comment: @SalmanA: what does "Does not seem to work" *mean*?  What happens?

Comment: In SQL Server 2000 and the original answer: `Syntax error converting datetime from character string`.

Comment: Try my updated example (with `UNION`). Your error could be raised because of wrong values in `DATE` type column. With real dates and string in the same column you have to convert all values to strings (i.e. `VARCHAR`s).

Answer (score 0):

Try this . This is w.r.to mysql

```
select if(Date <> '',Date,'xxxxxxx'),ShipmentRef,RecieptNo from table
```

Comment: An IF statement requires and AND or OR, so this came up with a syntax error before I executed the query.

Comment: @Natalie: in some sql flavors, `IF(expr,expr,expr)` is short for `CASE expr WHEN TRUE THEN expr ELSE expr END CASE`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(Date, 'InsertRandomStringHere') AS Date
FROM Table
```

Comment: Is the first or second 'Date' the field name?

Comment: first parameter is FieldName, second one is the alternative if Field Date is null and the AS-Part is the columnname for the resultquery

Comment: No, thats the NAME of the field as shown in your query result, if you call it 'Test' than its shown as 'Test' in your result